# React filter and then swap array elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
  const filterData = apiData.filter(data => {
      return this.shouldDisplayItem(
        data,
        [this.state.searchValue],
        this.state.filterKeyValue
      );
    }).filter(i => i.vid),
     x = 0,
      y = apiData.map(i => i.vid).indexOf(markerId);
  A[x] = A.splice(y, 1, A[x])[0];
```

For example, I have an `array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. First I want to filter value greater than 2 then I want to swap 7 and 8 via index number.

In the original project at first, I am doing some filter than on the second filter I am swapping two array object
can we filter two times same array in a single go?

Comment: yes you can do chaining of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filter out the array and then `swap` using the [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

```js
Array.prototype.swap = function (swapFirst,swapSecond) {
var x = this.findIndex(a=> a === swapFirst);
var y = this.findIndex(a=> a === swapSecond);
var b = this[y];
this[y] = this[x];
this[x] = b;
return this;

}


var apiData = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var filtered= apiData.filter(a=> a > 2).swap(7,8);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it simple with reduce()**

So here in reduce function i am first checking for `value > 2` condition.

- if it passes than i am checking for `value === 7` or `value===8` if any of them matches i change the value as you wanted.if not i just directly push  into output array.
- if `value > 2` fails i don't push that value in output array.

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let op = arr.reduce((op,cur)=>{
  if(cur>2){
    if( cur ===7)op.push(8);
    else if(cur === 8) op .push(7);
    else op.push(cur);
  }
  return op;
},[])

console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 1):

> than on the second filter I am swapping two array object

Array.prototype.filter should only filter elements from the array, not map / swap elements.

> can we filter two times same array in a single go?

Yes, for example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter((e, idx) => e + 1 === idx).filter(e => e%2 === 0)
```

can be replaced with:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter((e, idx) => e + 1 === idx &&  e%2 === 0)
```